# undefined method `confirm!' in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, devise, devise-confirmable

I am using devise since for my rails application and been using devise confirmable for users so they have to confirm their email after sign in!
I want to remove `:confirmable` and allow users to sign in without confirm their emails and I removed it and it works but my all rspec fails and it says

```
undefined method `confirm!' for #<User:0x007fc06db987e8>
```

There is no method like confirm!. How will I fix it ? (I have no clue) even updated my gem to 3.5.8.
I know I can skip the confirmation but i want to remove it!
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It's deprecated since 3.4.1 and [has been removed](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/26e22d8e953184b38a87f3a9b935db32258637d5) recently.

> Remove the Devise::Models::Confirmable#confirm! method, use confirm instead.

From: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#420---2016-07-01

Answer (score 2):

When you removing `:confirmable` module the `confirm!` method also will be removed from user instances. Because `confirm!` and `confirm` methods are located in the **Devise::Models::Confirmable**. In some your specs you use confirmation. Check out your specs.